# How do I merge elements in my array of strings in which there are leading and trailing parens?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, merge

In Ruby, let's say I have an array of strings

```
["a", "(b", "c)", "d", "e"]
```

How do I merge (with a space in between) strings in my array where the first character of one is a "(" and the last character of another one is ")"?  In the above example, I would want the resulting array to be

```
["a", "(b c)", "d", "e"]
```

Similarly, if my array were

```
["a", "(b", "e", "c)", "d"]
```

I would want the result to be

```
["a", "(b e c)", "d"]
```

However if the array were

```
["(a", "c"]
```

or

```
["c)", "e", "(b"]
```

I would want the arrays to be unchanged b/c in the first instance, there is no element with a ")" and in the second instance the element with the ")" is before the element beginning with the "(".  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first question would be, how did you get such a weird array? It looks like the result of splitting something that maybe shouldn't have been split that way.

I'm sure there are cleverer ways to do it, but a simple approach would be to iterate through the array and maintain a buffer of items to concatenate (or append to the end of the output if no closing item is found):

```
def regroup(arr)
  out, buf = [], []

  arr.each do |elem|
    if buf.empty? && !elem.start_with?('(')
      out << elem
    else
      buf << elem

      if elem.end_with?(')')
        out << buf.join(' ')

        buf.clear
      end
    end
  end

  out.concat(buf)
end
```

The main issue with this approach is that it doesn't handle nested groups. To support that, you need some way to ensure an equal number of opening and closing items before flushing the buffer:

```
def regroup(arr)
  out, buf, count = [], [], 0

  arr.each do |elem|
    if buf.empty? && !elem.start_with?('(')
      out << elem
    else
      buf << elem

      if elem.start_with?('(')
        count += 1
      elsif elem.end_with?(')')
        count -= 1
      end

      if count.zero?
        out << buf.join(' ')

        buf.clear
      end
    end
  end

  out.concat(buf)
end
```

This should be pretty efficient, since it's one iteration through the array with a minimal amount of objects created. Unfortunately, it still doesn't handle some cases, e.g. if `["(a", "(b", "c)"]` should return `["(a", "(b c)"]`. For that, you'll likely need a recursive function. Let me know if you'd like to see that solution.

**UPDATE:** It was much more difficult to implement a recursive solution than I thought it would be. I have a working version, but it's so ugly that I'm reluctant to share it! If I needed backtracking, I would probably use Amadan's regex solution or something similar. I also wrote a version of my solution with primitive backtracking:

```
def regroup(arr)
  out, pos = [], 0

  loop do
    should_retry = regroup_worker(arr.drop(pos)) do |elem, size=1|
      out << elem

      pos += size
    end

    break out unless should_retry
  end
end

def regroup_worker(arr)
  buf, count = [], 0

  arr.each do |elem|
    if buf.empty? && !elem.start_with?('(')
      yield elem
    else
      buf << elem

      if elem.start_with?('(')
        count += 1
      elsif elem.end_with?(')')
        count -= 1
      end

      if count.zero?
        yield buf.join(' '), buf.size

        buf.clear
      end
    end
  end

  # we have unbalanced parens, so let the caller consume the "bad" opening
  # paren and try again (returns false if nothing left to do)
  yield buf.first unless buf.empty?
end

regroup(["(a", "(b", "c)"]) # => ["(a", "(b c)"]
```

I hope this has been helpful! It was certainly an interesting problem to think about and try to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer probably fits you better, but just in case, here's an alternate approach, using string parsing:

```
def parse(str)
  str.scan(/
    (?<token> \g<paren> | \g<word>)
    (?<word> \w+){0}
    (?<paren> \( \g<token> (?:\s+ \g<token>)* \) ){0}
  /x).map(&:first)
end

arr = ["a", "(b", "c)", "d", "e"]
str = arr.join(' ')
parse(str)
# => ["a", "(b c)", "d", "e"]
parse("(a (b c) d) (e (f g)) (h i)")
# => ["(a (b c) d)", "(e (f g))", "(h i)"]
```

Comment: This is a really neat solution and it seems to handle the backtracking case, but it has some strange behavior. For example, `parse(["(a", "(b", "c)"].join(' '))` returns `["a", "(b c)"]`. Where'd the leading open paren go?

Comment: Yup, not a great fit for this specific case.